# Installing wheel with poetry from private github repo

Tags: github, python-wheel, python-poetry

I have a wheel committed to a private github repo that I am able to `pip install` in my projects with the github token. That is, I have a `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variable containing the token, which is allowing me to install from this kind of url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<github_user>/<repo_name>/master/dist/<my_wheel>.whl. That works fine for those projects.

Now, in a separate project, managed by `poetry`, I'd like to install that wheel from that repo as well. In this project, I can install the wheel if I simply download it manually from the repo, copy it into this project, and `poetry add` that local wheel. But I'd like to install it directly from the repo instead of the local file.

In pyproject.toml I've tried

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "<repo_name>"
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<github_user>/"
secondary = true
default = false
```

and variations of this, without any luck. I keep getting a 404 not found. I don't want to hardcode the github token obviously, but along with the above, I've tried:

```
poetry config repositories.<repo_name> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<github_user>/
poetry config http-basic.<repo_name> "read" "<github_token>"
poetry add https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<github_user>/<repo_name>/master/dist/<my_wheel>.whl
```

I've also tried with `poetry add git+https://raw.githubusercontent...` as well as with different variations of the url (eg. https://github.com/<github_user>/<repo_name>/tree/master/dist) but they all result in a 404.

In summary, **how can I `poetry add` a wheel from a private github repo?**

Comment: I'm getting it to work without adding any `[[tool.poetry.source]]` and simply `poetry add https://__token__:<my_token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<github_user>/<repo_name>/master/dist/<my_wheel>.whl`. But it is pasting my token in pyproject.toml and poetry.lock. How can I avoid that? I'm trying to set the token via `poetry config` but not sure about it.

Comment: According to [poetry issue 2348](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2348) or [issue 115](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/pull/115), poetry is currently unable to use or hide environment variables in pyproject.toml or poetry.lock...